# My evil brother scrambled my letter!

Tags: cipher

I decided to write an email to some friends one day. Unfortunately, my evil brother applied a code to it. My friends called and asked what it was supposed to say, but I've forgotten what. Can you help me decode it?

```
24    16.5  34    34  41.5
16.5  59    16.5  49  66.5  41.5  39  16.5
```

Comment: This puzzle is not a good example of a question we'd like to see on this site. For more information please see this meta question: http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/1717/code-puzzles-what-not-to-do . Perhaps some cleverly disguised clue to provide a definite starting direction would be enough to turn this into a good question.

Comment: @CodeNewbie I think it is easy enough to be solved without clues, but I will keep that in mind the next time.

Comment: @CodeNewbie Although the encryption itself may be a bit random, there were disguised clues, such as 16.5 being repeated 4 times, the spacing, and the .5s. There were enough hints for me to solve it in a minute or two through various tools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The letter says:

> Hello Everyone. By performing the transformation $(X-4)/2.5$ to each element and converting to letters (A=1, Z=26), you get Hello Everyone. I tried seeing if there's some significance to that transformation but I haven't been able to find any.

Comment: You got it correct! There's not much significance to the transformation. I made it up myself.